# Where did Euler derive the wave equation in 3d?

Tags: mathematical-physics, euler

Wikipedia claims that Euler was the first do derive the wave equation in 3d. In which of his writings can I find this?

Comment: Someone pointed me to Kline, pp. 518 for 2D, 521 for 3D: https://archive.org/details/MathematicalThoughtFromAncientToModernTimes/page/n535

Comment: [De la propagation du son](http://eulerarchive.maa.org/pages/E305.html), read to Berlin Academy in 1759, published 1766. Lagrange considered propagation of sound and 3D wave equation at about the same time, he corresponded with Euler and published in 1760, [Nouvelles recherches sur la nature et la propagation du son](http://sites.mathdoc.fr/cgi-bin/oeitem?id=OE_LAGRANGE__1_151_0).